# Is there a free, open source software that runs SAS code?

Tags: gratis, open-source, statistics

R was developed as a free, open source alternative to S. Much code written for S runs unaltered under R. Even the name R is a play on the name of S.

Is there a free, open source alternative to SAS? I didn't find any. I don't mean a software that does the same statistical calculations as SAS does. I can do them with R. My question is about a free software that runs code written in the SAS language.

It looks like writing such software would not be illegal. The company World Programming defended its use of the language of SAS in its own software WPS in the High Court of England and Wales in 2010. [[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Programming_System)]

SAS, please don't hate me.